# 親ViewGroupに設定したonTouchメソッドが呼び出されない

Tags: android, java

各画面で共通の右スワイプ処理を、各画面の親ViewGroupのonTouchメソッド内に記述しています。
TableLayoutやListViewを配置した画面では右スワイプ機能をきちんと動作させることができているのですが、
LinearLayoutに1つのTextViewを画面いっぱいに配置した(width、heightともmatch_parent)画面では、onTouchが呼ばれません。
試しにTextViewのサイズを小さくしてみて、TextViewの外側をタップすると正しくonTouchが呼ばれましたので、TextViewがブロックしているものと思うのですが、TextView上のタッチイベントを背景にそのまま投げるにはどのようにしたらよいでしょうか？
(右スワイプ機能がきちんと動作しているTableLayoutやListViewを配置した画面でもTextViewが乗っかっているので、もしかしたらonTouchが呼ばれないのはまた別の原因かもしれません。)

TextView自体のonTouchに機能を実装する方法でもいいのですが、TextViewではイベントを無視して下のレイヤーにイベントをそのまま投げるような仕組みがあるかも？(あったら嬉しい)と思い質問いたしました。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

恥ずかしながら、以下コードです。まずは問題の画面のコード。

```
//==============================================================================
// 画面起動　最初のアクティビティ
//==============================================================================
public class A990_License extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_990);
    }
}

//==============================================================================
// TextViewでいっぱいのフラグメント(B000_BaseFragmentを継承)
//==============================================================================
public class F990_License extends B000_BaseFragment {

    private static final String SELF_ID = "990";
    private static final int MAIN_LAYOUT_ID = R.layout.frg_990;
    private static final int BG_LAYOUT_ID = R.id.f990;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mSelfID = SELF_ID;
        mMainLayoutID = MAIN_LAYOUT_ID;
        mBGLayoutID   = BG_LAYOUT_ID;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        //ライセンス文字列を表示
        TextView lblLicense = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lblLicense);
        lblLicense.setText("〜〜〜〜〜〜");
        //lblLicense.setOnTouchListener(this); //これでもいいけれど...
    }
}

//==============================================================================
// 上記フラグメントの親クラス
//==============================================================================
public abstract class B000_BaseFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnTouchListener {

    protected int mMainLayoutID = 0;
    protected int mBGLayoutID = 0; //背景のビュー
    private GestureDetector mDetector; //ジェスチャー取得用

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //ジェスチャー取得用オブジェクトを生成
        mDetector = new GestureDetector(getActivity(), new MyGestureListener());
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (mMainLayoutID != 0) {
            return inflater.inflate(mMainLayoutID, container, false);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        //オプションメニューを表示
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        if (mBGLayoutID > 0) {
            //背景にタッチイベントリスナー(右スワイプ)をセット
            ViewGroup viBG = (ViewGroup)getActivity().findViewById(mBGLayoutID);
            viBG.setOnTouchListener(this);
        }
    }

    /**************************************************
     * イベント処理(View.OnTouchListener)
     **************************************************/
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        debug("TextViewをタップした場合もここを通ってほしいの。");
        boolean ret = mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return ret;
    }

    /**************************************************
     * ジェスチャー取得用インナークラス
     **************************************************/
    class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        //X軸方向スワイプのmin距離
        private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            debug("swipe距離 " + (event2.getX() - event1.getX()));
            /// 右スワイプ
            if (event2.getX() - event1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE) {
                swipeRight();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /// 右へスワイプイベント処理
    protected void swipeRight() {
        getActivity().finish(); //前画面に戻る
    }

}

//==============================================================================
// act_990.xml(アクティビティのxml)
//==============================================================================
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         tools:context=".A990_License"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment class="〜.F990_License"
          android:id="@+id/f990"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>

//==============================================================================
// frg_990.xml(フラグメントのxml)
//==============================================================================
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          tools:context=".F990_License"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblLicense"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" //--------ここを「wrap_content」にして実験した
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:background="#00ff00"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

次は、期待通りにタッチイベントが取得できている画面のコードです。
TableLayoutでTextView(`wrap_content`)も使用しています。

```
//==============================================================================
// 画面起動　アクティビティ
//==============================================================================
public class A940_Upd extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_940);
    }
}

//==============================================================================
// TableLayoutを使ったフラグメント(こちらにもTextViewがあるが、想定の動きをしている)
//==============================================================================
public class F940_Upd extends B000_BaseInputFragment {

    private static final String SELF_ID = "940";
    private static final int MAIN_LAYOUT_ID = R.layout.frg_940;
    private static final int MENU_LAYOUT_ID = 0;
    private static final int BG_LAYOUT_ID = R.id.f940;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mSelfID = SELF_ID;
        mMainLayoutID = MAIN_LAYOUT_ID;
        mMenuLayoutID = MENU_LAYOUT_ID;
        mBGLayoutID   = BG_LAYOUT_ID;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        //引数を取得
        //タイトル表示
    }
}

//==============================================================================
// 上記フラグメントの親クラス
//==============================================================================
public abstract class B000_BaseInputFragment extends B000_BaseFragment 
    implements TextWatcher, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<MyCellData.List> {

    /**************************************************
     * イベント処理(View.OnTouchListener)
     **************************************************/
    /// タッチ時処理
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        if (super.onTouch(view, event)) {
            return true; //親側でイベント処理を終えた場合

        } else {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    //背景がタップされたらキーボードを隠す
                    if (view.getId() == mBGLayoutID) {
                        AAA.closeKeyboard(view);
                        return true;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**************************************************
     * イベント処理(TextWatcher)
     **************************************************/
    //〜省略〜

    /**************************************************
     * LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<>
     **************************************************/
    //〜省略〜
}


//==============================================================================
// act_940.xml(アクティビティのxml)
//==============================================================================
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             tools:context=".A940_Upd"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment class="〜.F940_Upd"
              android:id="@+id/f940"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>    

//==============================================================================
// frg_940.xml(フラグメントのxml)
//==============================================================================
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:background="#cccccc">

    <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:minHeight="?attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
              android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
              android:layout_marginBottom="0.2dp"
              android:background="#ffffff">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/lbl"
                  android:labelFor="@+id/txtTel"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="Tel"/>

        <EditText android:id="@+id/txtTel"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                  android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                  android:maxLines="1"
                  android:inputType="phone"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnTel"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:src="@mipmap/ic_call_black_24dp"
                     android:background="@null"
                     android:contentDescription="Dial"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: AOSSのコードを見た限りはTextViewがタッチイベントをハンドルすることがありえます。TextViewがタッチイベントをハンドルしてしまえば、親には通知されません。実際に書かれたコードがわからないため、ハンドルされている原因は不明です。可能ならコードを質問内容に追記してください。

Comment: コードを追記いたしました。無駄に長いような気も致しますが、おかしな点等ありましたらご指摘ください。

Comment: `android:autoLink`の指定を取ってみたら動かないでしょうか。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！`autoLink`外したら動きました(ﾟ∇ ﾟ);ﾅﾝﾄ...　
リンク機能は残したいのですが、共存させることはできないのでしょうか？(`clickable`や`focusable`を設定してみたりしているのですがうまくいかず)

Comment: `autoLink`を外せばイベントが発生するようになりましたので、この画面ではひとまずリンクを使用しない方法をとることにしました。原因が分かりすっきりしました。<(_ _)>

Comment: `TextView`自体がイベントを取ってしまうので共存は難しいと思います。MovementMethodなどを利用することで別途リンク指定をすることで期待されている機能が実現できるかもしれません。または`TextView`を継承した独自の`TextView`を作成してそちらから別にタッチイベントを通知させる仕組みを用意する方法も考えられます。

Comment: お教え頂いた方法で試してみます！助かりました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

一応回答として残します。

`TextView`は`autoLink`の指定や、`Editable`の指定などがあると`TextView`自体がタッチイベントをハンドルすることがあります。
`TextView`がイベントをハンドルしてしまった場合は親の`View`にはタッチイベントは通知されません。

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.lciel.jp/blog/2013/12/03/android-touch-event/
こちらの記事が参考になると思います。
既に一読済みでしたらすみません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
こちらのページは何度も目を通しているのですが理解しきれていない状況です。^^;アタマワルイノデ...
View(TextView)でイベントを処理していない場合は、その下層のViewGroupのイベントが呼ばれる、と解釈していたのですが、
「タッチイベントを処理しない」とは「リスナーも設定せず何もしない」ではなく「タッチイベントを設定してfalseを返せ」という意味なのでしょうか？
TextViewにセットリスナーすると想定の動きになったのですが、TextViewが複数あるようなページの場合、全てのTextViewにリスナーを設定するのが一般的なのでしょうか？(androidもjavaも初心者なのでこういったところの感覚がわからないでおります。)
TableLayoutやListViewを使った画面でもTextViewを使用していますが、こちらは特に何もせず背景のタップイベントが呼ばれるので、???です。

Comment: 他のサイトに答えが書かれている場合でも、要点を回答内に記載し、リンクはあくまで参考情報にとどめてください。リンク先が変更・削除された場合に回答の価値が失われることも防ぎます。 - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14512)

Comment: @yasu
わかりました。
以後、気を付けます。

Comment: 回答は後から編集できますよ! 上のように追加で質問が来た時など回答内容を更新できます。今度機会があればお試しください。